# Bundle org.apache.ant could not be found. (Gradle and wuff)

Tags: eclipse, apache, plugins, gradle

I am trying to covert some existing eclipse plugin to gradle using the "wuff" plugin at
https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff/wiki/Convert-existing-Eclipse-plugins-and-apps-to-Gradle

I followed the tutorial and created the sample app successfully, but when trying to convert my own plugin i get the following error:

### Bundle name org.apache.ant could not be found

The  org.apache.ant is in my Require-Bundle in the Manifest.MF

Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core,
 org.apache.ant